# Taylor Series of a Sine

Tags: java, taylor-series

I'm currently in a Java class at my university and we've been asked to code a Taylor Series equation to compute a Sine function. I've coded what makes sense to me, and I've tried debugging every section of code I can think of to make sure all of the parts are functioning the way I think they should, but the program still isn't functioning right. So, I'm hoping someone might look at this and spot what I'm doing wrong.

this is the equation: [Taylor Series Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbLzN.png)

```
public class Sine {

public static int factorial(int a) {
    int num = a;
    if (a == 1) return 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++){
    a = a * i;
    }   return a;
}
public static double numerator(double x, int power) {
    double ret = Math.pow(x, power);
    return ret;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int power = 1;
    int iter = 0;
    double x = Math.PI/4;

    int sign = 1;
    while (iter != 10) {
        iter++;
        System.out.println("Iteration " + iter + ": " + x);
        x += sign * numerator(x, power)/factorial(power);
        power += 2;
        sign *= -1;
    }
    System.out.println("\nTaylor Series, Final: " + x);
System.out.println("Value of Sine: " + Math.sin(Math.PI/4));
}
}
```

I'm just very confused what's going on and why it's not working.

Comment: Try printing the value of `factorial(int)` for increasing values of `a`. You might get a surprise.

Comment: (By the way, `factorial(0)` is wrong).

Comment: What do you mean 'isn't working right'? Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Looks like you're going up to `factorial(21)`, which is far too big for an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong (thanks @AndyTurner) is trying to store large factorials in an `int`, which of course can only store numbers up to about 2 billion.

To avoid having to deal with large numbers and their limited accuracies, you could use the following principle, that applies to the Taylor series for sines.

> Term in x<sup>n</sup> = (Term in x<sup>n-2</sup>) `* - x * x / n / (n-1)`.

For example, if you've already calculated x<sup>5</sup> / 5!, then the best way to calculate -x<sup>7</sup> / 7! is to multiply the number you've already calculated by -x<sup>2</sup> / 6 / 7.

If you calculate your terms this way, then add them up, you avoid all the problems that come with dealing with large numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but I must be misunderstanding what you have in code. "x^n" (meaning the numerator?) should be replaced with x^n-2 * - x * x/n/(n-1)? I'm very confused, I apologize.

Comment: Does the sentence I've just added help you understand?