# what could be the time complexity of sine function by taylor's series?

Tags: c, math, time-complexity, calculus, taylor-series

I did search everywhere, even on SO.
and scholarly articles on google are far beyond my mental capabilities.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813627/taylor-series-of-a-sine) is as close as it gets, but doesn't answer my question.
There is no answer for this as Far as I have looked for. Believe Me.
( But feel free to prove me wrong )

I  have a homework problem for calculating Time complexity of sine function using Taylor's expansion of sine(x) function.
I am not asking for Taylor series or Taylor series function program, but its **time complexity**.
I know the next term in Taylor expansion is given as :

> Term in x^n = (Term in x^n-2) * x * x / n / (n-1)

The function snippet is this:

```
double sine(double x) {
int n;
double sum, term;
n = 3;
sum = x;
term = x;
while(isgreater(fabs(term), 0.0000000001)) {
    term = (term * x * x) / ( n * (n -1));
        if(n % 4 == 3)
            sum -= term;
    else
            sum += term;
         n = n + 2;
}   
return sum;
}
```

fabs() is the function for absolute value
and 0.0000000001 is the precision required.
If my understanding is correct, the code will stop when the value of the last calculated term is less than/equal to the precision float set.

My deduction so far is maybe the Time complexity will depend on x^2/n^2 ?
or it is not deduce-able cause we don't know at which specific index/number the tern will be less then precision float ?

*Math is not strong with me, But thankfully there are Masters like you out there :)*

Comment: If you include the minus sign in the term computation,  `term = - (term * x * x) / ( n * (n -1));` then you can omit the following conditional.

Comment: You shouldn't be letting `x` grow indefinitely; rather, you should limit the domain of `x` to at least `[0, Pi/2]`, and use the symmetry properties of the sine curve to calculate values for large `x`.

Comment: @LutzL yes you are correct, My teacher did it to simplify the explanation of the function.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks for the valuable addition ! I'll keep it in mind for my next programs :)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it is [0,Pi/4] actually, see http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.67.5616 (no need for emailing the author, the paper has copies spread all over the net)

Comment: @deamentiaemundi yes, I did say "at least" (i.e. the least amount of work you can do to ensure sine does not repeat its value); however the author said `[-Pi/4, Pi/4]` (plus some multiple of `Pi/2`) which I find confusing. I suppose you could reduce to *any* rational fraction of Pi and use multi-angle formulae, while that would also reduce the output precision.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Agree about the usefulness of limiting the calculation range. Note  that reduction itself is tricky to do well exceeding the challenges of `sine_sub_range()` code. [Good to the Last Bit](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf)

Comment: `fabs()` is a standard math.h function that returns the absolute value.  This is not the same as "fabs() is the function for absolute value(modulus function |x| )" as there is no _modulus_ happening.  If your code is using the standard `fabs()`, state, that, else provide the code for your custom `fabs()`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog `sin` is an odd function, that is `-sin(x) = sin(-x)`, so [-Pi/4,Pi/4] can be reduced to [0,Pi/4].

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I know; I was just confused about why he chose to represent it that way, because neither sin or cos need the negative half of the range.

Comment: @chux fabs() is a standard fn from math.h, i put in description its description just in case someone asks abt it.

Comment: @DevX Good that code uses the _standard_ function `fabs()`, yet IMO, the   post has an incorrect description as there is no _modulus_ involved.

Comment: @Chux edited according to your advice  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what could be the time complexity of sine function by Taylor's series?
>   Math is not strong with me

As an adjunct to [LutzL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985262/2410359) fine analysis, sometimes a sanity check and *visual* of simple testing the code provides insight as to the time complexity.

```
#define N 1000000
clock_t test_sine(double x) {
  clock_t c1 = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sine(x);
  }
  clock_t c2 = clock();
  return c2 - c1;
}

void test_sines(void) {
  double x0 = 0;
  double x1 = 70;
  double dx = 0.2;
  for (double x = x0; x <= x1; x += dx) {
    printf("%f \t %d\n", x, (int) test_sine(x));
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  test_sines();
}
```

Sample output

```
0   16
0.2 78
0.4 93
0.6 94
0.8 94
1   124
...
```

Graphing this is fairly linear once `x > 3`.

[image]

Looking closer we see a step in time every power and using the trend looks very close to `t = pow(x,1/3.)`

```
void test_sines(void) {
  double x0 = 0.0000000001/2;
  double x1 = 1;
  double dx = pow(2, 1.0/5);
  for (double x = x0; x <= x1; x *= dx) {
```

[image]

---

Using `clock()` is fairly crude, yet provides a visual to the analysis.

With `x * x`, I would have expected `term` to affect `isgreater()` about every `sqrt(x)` as that would oblige another loop iteration.

**Conclusion**: time complexity for small values about `power(x,1.0/d)` (2.0 <= d <= 3.1) and linear for large values.

---

Note there are a number of issues about the quality of OP's `sine()` that render its result weak for many `x`.  For many values `x` > 900, `sine(x)` was an infinite loop.

Comment: Good lord ! Thank you very much for this huge analysis ! :D

Comment: @DevX To be clear, I was not trying to assess the time complexity of an algorithm.  I was assessing  the time complexity of a real C function `sine()`, its application of the Taylor's series, questionable termination condition and  issues of limited precision, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It seems rather straight-forward that the termination condition is

```
abs(x^n/n!) < eps.
```

What is not as straight-forward is to solve this for `n`. Even using the Sterling approximation, you would still have to solve

```
abs(e*x/n)^n < eps
```

You could make some simplifying assumptions to get upper bounds, such as `n > 6*abs(x)` so that then you would have to solve

```
(e/6)^n < eps  =>  n > log(eps)/log(e/6).
```

However, long before this `n = O(abs(x))` really kicks in your calculation gets murdered by cancellation errors as the term where `n=round(abs(x))` has size `e^n` and the surrounding terms have to reduce that back to an absolute value less than 1. At `x=35` this means you lose all digits of the sum to the cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, you would use the periodicity of the function and keep a bounded number of terms, hence O(1).

In the theoretical world, you need larger and larger numbers because of the exponential growth of x^n, and the complexity of multiplication enters into play. As explained by LutzL, the number of terms must exceed x, and the global complexity must be like O(x M(log(x))) where M(k) denotes the cost of a multiplication of k-digits numbers. (O(k²) for the naive implementation, O(k Log k Log Log k) for more efficient ones).